# Oracle equivalency of TSQL 'output'

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql, plsql

We are converting code from TSQL to PL/SQL, in one of our TSQL queries we have 'output' statement which needs to be converted to PL/SQL. What is the PL/SQL equivalency of TSQL 'output'?

Comment: Just guessing, as I do not know TSQL, but perhaps [DBMS_OUTPUT](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_output.htm#ARPLS036). When asking for an equivalent function perhaps it is best to describe, or provide a link to the original.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know MS SQL Server so I Googled for the `output` clause.

As far as I can tell, Oracle offers the `RETURNING INTO` clause for such a purpose. Here's an example (you'll notice that it isn't as *pretty* as T-SQL's `output` ...).

Sample table:

```
SQL> select * from test order by deptno;

    DEPTNO ENAME      JOB
---------- ---------- ---------
        20 ADAMS      CLERK
        20 SMITH      CLERK
        20 SCOTT      ANALYST
        20 JONES      MANAGER
        30 TURNER     SALESMAN
        30 BLAKE      MANAGER
        30 JAMES      CLERK
        30 WARD       SALESMAN
        30 ALLEN      SALESMAN
        30 MARTIN     SALESMAN

10 rows selected.
```

Let's delete rows that belong to `deptno = 20`, return them into collection and display what's been deleted.

```
SQL> create or replace type t_row as object
  2    (deptno number, ename varchar2(20), job varchar2(20));
  3  /

Type created.

SQL> create or replace type t_tab as table of t_row;
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    l_tab t_tab;
  3  begin
  4    delete from test
  5      where deptno = 20
  6      returning t_row(deptno, ename, job)        --> RETURNING clause, here
  7      bulk collect into l_tab;
  8
  9    dbms_output.put_line('Deleted rows:');
 10    for i in l_tab.first .. l_tab.last loop
 11      dbms_output.put_line(l_tab(i).deptno ||' '||
 12                           rpad(l_tab(i).ename, 10, ' ')  ||' '||
 13                           l_tab(i).job);
 14    end loop;
 15  end;
 16  /
Deleted rows:
20 SMITH      CLERK
20 JONES      MANAGER
20 SCOTT      ANALYST
20 ADAMS      CLERK

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

What's left in the table:

```
SQL> select * from test order by deptno;

    DEPTNO ENAME      JOB
---------- ---------- ---------
        30 ALLEN      SALESMAN
        30 WARD       SALESMAN
        30 JAMES      CLERK
        30 BLAKE      MANAGER
        30 TURNER     SALESMAN
        30 MARTIN     SALESMAN

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```